# Where does this HTTP error come from : "Unable to contact target server after 1 tries."?

Tags: asp.net, http, http-error

Some rare times, an HTTP error is displayed while accessing a page in a ASP.NET Web application :

> An HTTP error occurred while getting:
>
> **http://mydomain.com/mypage.aspx**
>
> Details: "Unable to contact target server after 1 tries.".

This message is displayed on a blank white page, without anything else. This doesn't look like an ASP .NET error page. IIS isn't logging anything special at the time of the error.

I really don't understand **who is raising the error**. Could it come from the code ? ASP ? IIS ?

The error is random, occurred with 2 users located on totally different company (so the error is probably not raised by some internal proxy), but always on the same page. The page isn't doing anything special, but I have to know if it could be code-related first !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the response header. It could be a transparent proxy server.

Comment: It would be interesting for sure. Unfortunaly, I cannot reproduce the error. Only a few users saw it in production, and I can't ask them to debug it...

Comment: The "connect timed out" message isn't the same as mine, but the general error message does look the same.
I then tought it could mean this is a Internet Explorer error, but a user got it on Firefox on OS X...
Thank you, but I'm still stuck here.